# css responsive flex layout column to row

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to create a component which should be responsive. 
Below is the markup of the component

```
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="weather-card">
    <span> <h2>Singapore  </h2><span>
          <span> 28&deg </span>
  </div>


  <div class="weather-list">
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Monday </span>
      <span> 25&deg </span>
    </div>
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Tue </span>
      <span> 35&deg </span>
    </div>
    <div class="week-item">
      <span> Wed </span>
      <span> 45&deg </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week-graph">
  </div>
</div>

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.weather-card {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.weather-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.week-item {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

I want the items with class Weather-list to be responsive. The items should stack one below other in mobile. Specifying flex-flow is not working properly.

Also how should I specify the height and width of the whole component so that It will work properly who ever consumes it.

This is just the markup, you can see the react app that I am trying to build in the codesandbox link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/weather-report-rgu7y-regtl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `styles.css` file, changing your media query to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .weather-container {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .weather-list {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Will get everything to stack in the middle.